# Asking player numbers then assigning player names to them

Tags: python, python-3.x, blackjack

I wanted to ask how many players there are first , then depending on how many players they are playing the game, I wanted to loop through and ask their names as input and then assigning it to their player numbers.
First: it will ask player numbers
Second: it will ask their names
Third: then it will create their names as variables

Here is what I tried but it is returning :

```
player_nums =int(input("how many players are there? "))
playernum = True
while playernum:
    if player_nums >7 or player_nums == 0 :
        print( "there cant be more than 7 players")
        print("please entre the player numbers again")
        player_nums =int(input("how many players are there? "))
    elif player_nums == 6 :
        player_one = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_two = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_three = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_four = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_five = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_six = input("please write ur name playerone")
        playernum = False
    elif playernum ==5:
        player_one = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_two = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_three = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_four = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_five = input("please write ur name playerone")
        playernum = False
    elif playernum ==4:
        player_one = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_two = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_three = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_four = input("please write ur name playerone")
        playernum = False
    elif playernum == 3: 
        player_one = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_two = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_three = input("please write ur name playerone")
        playernum = False
    elif playernum ==2:
        player_one = input("please write ur name playerone")
        player_two = input("please write ur name playerone")
    elif playernum == 1:
        player_one = input("please write ur name playerone")
        playernum = False
    else:
        continue
print(player_one)
```

Here is an another method i tried but it wont work, I dont know how it is not working:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name= name

    def new_name(self):
        self.new_names = input('what is your name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_names

user = Player("")
player_nums =int(input("how many players are there? "))
playernum = True
while playernum:
    if player_nums >7 or player_nums == 0 :
        print( "there cant be more than 7 players")
        print("please entre the player numbers again")
        player_nums =int(input("how many players are there? "))
    else:
        for i in range(1,player_nums):
            user = Player.new_name(user)
print(user.new_name)
```

I wanted to loop through the player number to assign individual names to their player numbers, for example if there is 5 players, Player 1 : input (his name) player 2 : input (his name) etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question as written is very confusing but from what I gather you want to:

1. Ask how many players are participating (0 < n <=7).
2. For each identified player associate a name with the player number.

In order to perform this task in an orderly, neat and efficient manner, you should utilize the inherent data structures available to you within python.

```
def start_game():
    while plyr_count := int(input('How Many Players are there? ')):
            if plyr_count <= 7:
                break
            print('Number of players must be less than or equal to 7, try again')
    players = []
    for i in range(plyr_count):
        players.append(input(f"Enter Player {i+1}'s name "))
    return players
```

Then when executing start_game, you will get:
How Many Players are there? 12
Number of players must be less than or equal to 7, try again

```
How Many Players are there? 4
Enter Player 1's name Bob
Enter Player 2's name Tom
Enter Player 3's name Judy
Enter Player 4's name Nancy
['Bob', 'Tom', 'Judy', 'Nancy']
```

f you would like to create a player class and use this in the above code this is how I would approach it.

```
# The player Class definition
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):  # Allows for printing Class
        return self.name  

# Update Code to utilize player class in start_game
def start_game():
    while plyr_count := int(input('How Many Players are there? ')):
            if plyr_count <= 7:
                break
            print('Number of players must be less than or equal to 7, try again')
    players = []
    for i in range(plyr_count):
        players.append(Player(input(f"Enter Player {i+1}'s name ")))
    return players
```

Comment: Thanks, So from players[] i can call the players with players[0] right? I just learned about classes and OOP and wanted to subscribe my idea using class. Is there a way I can implement class into this.

Comment: Sure, see update to answer